# Uncaught TypeError: $.get(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my code  .. I am recieving error in console as   Uncaught TypeError: $.get(...).then is not a function..error is in 18 th line

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="requestButton">HTTP Request</button>
<ul id="myList"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ulElm = document.querySelector("#myList");
    var first = false;
    var chatList;
    function updateChat() {
        console.log("update Chat called");
        $.get("http://projecttester.16mb.com/makejson.php")
        .then(function(data) {//ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
            if(!first) {
                chatList = JSON.parse(data);
                chatList.forEach(function(item) {
                    var liElm = document.createElement('li');
                    liElm.innerHTML = item.Message;
                    ulElm.appendChild(liElm);
                });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: use [`done()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) not `then()`

Comment: got this error Uncaught TypeError: $.get(...).done is not a function

Comment: `$.get` is not thenable, use `.done()`, `.always()` or callback `$.get(URL, callback)` instead. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: since you have AngularJS, use [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like `$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="requestButton">HTTP Request</button>
<ul id="myList"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ulElm = document.querySelector("#myList");
    var first = false;
    var chatList;
    function updateChat() {
        console.log("update Chat called");
        $.get("http://projecttester.16mb.com/makejson.php", function(data) {
            if(!first) {
                chatList = JSON.parse(data);
                chatList.forEach(function(item) {
                    var liElm = document.createElement('li');
                    liElm.innerHTML = item.Message;
                    ulElm.appendChild(liElm);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
```